Failed installing @expo/webpack-config in my Expo React Native 0.74.3 Bridgeless Architecture
When I try installing the webpack config to allow me setup Sign in with google as demonstrated on https://codewithbeto.dev/projects/sign-in-with-google-expo with the dependencies listed below i get this error when i try installing the @expo/webpack-config:
Need help.
npx expo install @react-native-google-signin/google-signin
› Installing 1 other package using npm

npm install --save @react-native-google-signin/google-signin
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @expo/webpack-config@19.0.1
npm ERR! Found: expo@51.0.22
npm ERR! node_modules/expo
npm ERR!   peer expo@"" from expo-application@5.9.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/expo-application
npm ERR!     expo-application@"~5.9.0" from expo-auth-session@5.5.2
npm ERR!     node_modules/expo-auth-session
npm ERR!       expo-auth-session@"~5.5.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer expo@"" from expo-asset@10.0.10
npm ERR!   node_modules/expo-asset
npm ERR!     expo-asset@"~10.0.10" from expo@51.0.22
npm ERR!   25 more (expo-build-properties, expo-calendar, expo-constants, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer expo@"^49.0.7 || ^50.0.0-0" from @expo/webpack-config@19.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@expo/webpack-config
npm ERR!   @expo/webpack-config@"~19.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: expo@50.0.20
npm ERR! node_modules/expo
npm ERR!   peer expo@"^49.0.7 || ^50.0.0-0" from @expo/webpack-config@19.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/@expo/webpack-config
npm ERR!     @expo/webpack-config@"~19.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/macbookair/.npm/_logs/2024-08-23T09_49_34_857Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/macbookair/.npm/_logs/2024-08-23T09_49_34_857Z-debug-0.log
Error: npm install --save @react-native-google-signin/google-signin exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm install --save @react-native-google-signin/google-signin exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:42:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:626:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:511:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
...
at spawnAsync (/Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:7:23)
at NpmPackageManager.runAsync (/Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/build/node/BasePackageManager.js:41:42)
at /Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/build/node/NpmPackageManager.js:37:20
at /Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/build/utils/spawn.js:19:34
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
macbookair@Mac-K0C6JRHVF7 voomplatformv1 % npx expo install @expo/webpack-config
› Installing 1 SDK 51.0.0 compatible native module using npm

npm install
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: voomplatformv1@51.0.46
npm ERR! Found: expo@51.0.30
npm ERR! node_modules/expo
npm ERR!   expo@"~51.0.22" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer expo@"^49.0.7 || ^50.0.0-0" from @expo/webpack-config@19.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@expo/webpack-config
npm ERR!   @expo/webpack-config@"~19.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /Users/macbookair/.npm/_logs/2024-08-23T10_40_28_141Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /Users/macbookair/.npm/_logs/2024-08-23T10_40_28_141Z-debug-0.log
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 1
at ChildProcess.completionListener (/Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:42:23)
at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:626:26)
at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:511:28)
at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
...
at spawnAsync (/Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:7:23)
at NpmPackageManager.runAsync (/Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/build/node/BasePackageManager.js:41:42)
at /Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/build/node/NpmPackageManager.js:36:20
at /Users/macbookair/Documents/voomplatformv1/node_modules/@expo/package-manager/build/utils/spawn.js:19:34
I tried installing with the command and it failed everytime. Im expecting a solution to help me start configuring my project to allow me signin with google.
Im running react native 0.74.3 bridgeless mode on the frontend with an Express and Mongo backend.
Will be grateful with the assistance.
